# THREE.js get GridHelper coordinates from MouseClick

Tags: three.js, coordinate-systems

How can I get the coordinate of - or IN - the `GridHelper` I’m tapping on? Especially when there’s going to be an actual Terrain `Mesh` sitting on top of the `GridHelper`?

[image]

My `GridHelper` is set-up as follows:

```
let  helperGrid = new THREE.GridHelper(600, 120, "yellow", “blue”);
```

So the distance between each grid line is 5  (cause 600 / 12 = 5)

As I click around the screen, I’d like to know where in the Grid I clicked on. Did I click somewhere in the very first square for example? Which means clicking (for the X value) anywhere between (0, 0, 0) and (5, 0, 0), and for Z-values anywhere between (0, 0, 0) and (0, 0, -5)?

I was going to try and calculate this using my clicked mouse-coordinates, which I calculate using the `mousedown` event, in the usual manner:

```
mousePositionVector.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
mousePositionVector.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
```

But that translates into really *tiny* decimal numbers. For example when I click anywhere in the very first grid box - meaning between x = 0 and x = 5, I’m getting mouse position values such as:

```
 ( 0.07309721175584016 , 0.03186646433990892 )
```

or:

```
( 0.09269027882441594 , 0.02427921092564489 )
```

etc.

Meanwhile, the corresponding  `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` values - for the very same tap event - are:

```
clientXY = ( 740 , 634 )
```

So neither set of values seem to be pointing me in the right direction.

Asides from all this, I’d like to eventually place a terrain over this grid - which means that the `rayCaster` I use will catch the vertex of the Terrain `Mesh` I create, which may further complicate the issues.

What’s the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already a demo with your exact scenario: [Raycasting with a terrain mesh](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_terrain_raycast) (click on the bottom-right `<>` icon to view the source).

When the raycast intersects with the terrain mesh, it'll return an object with the following properties, [as explained in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.intersectObject): `{ distance, point, face, faceIndex, object }`, so if you want to know the `x, z` coordinates of where you're hovering, simply look at the `.point` property of the intersected object:

```js
function onMouseMove( event ) {

    // Get screen-space x/y
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    // Perform raycast
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    // See if the ray from the camera into the world hits our mesh
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( terrainMesh );

    // Check if an intersection took place
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        const posX = intersects[0].point.x;
        const posZ = intersects[0].point.z;
        console.log(posX, posZ);
    }

}
```

Finally, if you want to know the position in increments of 5 units, just do a little rounding trick:

```js
const posX = Math.round(intersects[0].point.x / 5) * 5;
const posZ = Math.round(intersects[0].point.z / 5) * 5;
```